# How to check if all ids inside an array exist in a csv file?

Tags: perl, grep

I have two arrays:

```
BLOCK_X= (1,2,3,4)
BLOCK_Y= (3,6,2,5)
```

**CSV**

```
BLOCK_X,BLOCK_Y;DISPLAYTYPE;URBAN;LINKLENGTH;PARENTID;SOURCEID;TRUCKTOLL
1;3;19;;;;1;0
2;6;21;;;;2;0
3;2;23;;;;3;0
```

Now I will check if all values of *BLOCK_X* and *BLOCK_Y* are inside the field `BLOCK_X` and `BLOCK_Y` of that csv file. Otherwise it should appeare a message which values are not inside.

In this case it should appear that value `BLOCK_X = 4`, `BLOCK_Y = 5` are not inside the csv file. How can I realize this?

Answer (score 1):

With  [splice](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) try the follow

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @BLOCK_X= (1,2,3,4);

my @BLOCK_Y= (3,6,2,5);

open my $wh,"<","file.csv";

<$wh>; #remove header

while(<$wh>)
{

    my ($x,$y) = (split";")[0,1];  #store the first column in $x and second column in $y

    foreach my $i(0..$#BLOCK_X)
    {

      splice(@BLOCK_X,$i,1) if(($BLOCK_X[$i]) && ($x == int($BLOCK_X[$i]))); #Check if it is values are equal and variable is declared.

      splice(@BLOCK_Y,$i,1) if(($BLOCK_Y[$i]) && ($y == int($BLOCK_Y[$i])));

    }
}

print "@BLOCK_X\n";
print "@BLOCK_Y\n";
```